# Setting up a subdomain with domain hosted externally

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, subdomain

**I'll start with a brief description of our setup:**
Our domain, let's call it domain.com is hosted by an external company (GoDaddy) that points to our external IP. Internally we have a Domain Controller (Windows Server 2008), a Web Server (for domain.com) and an Issue Tracking Software.

**What I want:**
To create a subdomain, call it issues.domain.com, that connects to our Issue Tracking Server, let's say it has an internal ip of 192.168.1.123.

**What I tried:**
I added a new zone in our DNS Manager and called it domain.com and added an A record that points to the Issue Tracking Server. This works for my PC whose primary DNS is set to our DC but issues.domain.com isn't accessible externally nor can anyone access it internally without changing their DNS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologize in advance for any misuse of terminology, I'm a programmer and this networking stuff is quite new to me.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want it to be accessible externally then you have to create an A record for it in your external DNS.

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty, I tried that but the issue now is that issues.domain.com takes me to our web server (I get our homepage and not the Issue Tracking homepage).

Comment: It sounds to me like you haven't got the A record pointed to the correct ip address.

Comment: Which A record do you mean? The record hosted on GoDaddy is pointed to our external facing IP and the internal A record is pointed to our tracking server's IP

Comment: Well the external A record has to be pointed at the public ip address that you're forwarding to the internal ip address of the tracking server. It sounds like that's your problem. Is the tracking server a web server? Do you have only 1 public ip address and is that ip address forwarded to a different internal web server?

Comment: That would makes sense. The tracking server is a web server yes (it's Bugzilla if that helps). We only have the one IP and as far as I know it's forwarded to our internal web server IP (unfortunately I didn't set this network up so I don't know this for sure)